# how run a package?

Tags: ros, gazebo, roslaunch, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all
i have a package named Quadrotor-master and containing
include folder/launch folder/src folder
and
CMakeLists.txt/package.xml/README.md files
i want to run this package but when i using roslaunch Quadrotor-master quadrotor.launch
command i see this error that ::[Quadrotor-master] is not a package  or launch file name

what is wrong in my commands?
i put my package o home folder of ubuntu/there is not any setup file in my folder.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67231/how-run-a-package?/) by [masoudpz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5391/masoudpz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's not a [valid package name](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Names#Package_Resource_Names) many of the tools will fail with that name.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [masoudpz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5391/masoudpz/) on 2013-07-13**:
http://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/

thanks tfoote
but how i can fix this problem?? i changed package name but it does not work !

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-07-14**:
Please update your question to reflect what your problems are. Without more information we cannot help you more.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-07-14**:
please also make sure to copy and paste everything from the terminal so that we can reproduce your problem, see exactly what you are typing and what the output you're getting is.